# Any more efficient method of converting a string integer to int than convert.toint32

Tags: c#

Is there a more efficient method of converting a string integer to int rather than using `Convert.ToInt32()` in c#?

I have a program which converts a lot of strings to integers.  These values are read from a text file in string format.

Comment: Did you try using `Int.Parse()`?

Comment: How fast is it currently, and how fast do you need it to be? (I'd personally use `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse`, but there's not much difference.)

Comment: Do you have any bound on the length of your string?

Comment: @Douglas ya it would be a max of 10 million

Comment: @JonSkeet i dont know how fast it is.I just wanted to know if any other type of conversion would give a better performance

Comment: @Jay: If you don't know whether it's fast enough or not, then you're concentrating on the wrong thing. Write your code as simply and readably as you can so that it works, then test the performance and see whether it's good enough.

Comment: The main issue here is correctness. You should specify the culture you want explicitly.

Comment: Are all your string values valid? Or do you need to handle parsing errors?

Answer (score 3):

No, probably not, at least not by far. I tried this quick and dirty benchmark:

```
private static int toint(string s) {
    int res = 0;
    foreach (var c in s) {
        res = 10*res + (c - '0');
    }
    return res;
}

static void Main() {
    var s = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 10000000 ; i++) {
        if (Convert.ToInt32("112345678") == 0) break;
    }
    var m = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; i++) {
        if (toint("112345678") == 0) break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now-m, m-s);
}
```

My `toint` method skips all sorts of validations, and gets a result that is only a 40% improvement on `Convert.ToInt32`: 1.14 s vs. 1.86 s.

Adding just a basic validation to the dirty `toint` eliminates its advantage almost entirely: this method

```
private static int toint(string s) {
    int res = 0;
    foreach (var c in s) {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            res = 10*res + (c - '0');
    }
    return res;
}
```

runs in 1.62 s, or a 13% improvement **while staying fundamentally incorrect**.

Comment: 40% can be a very significant improvement if this happens in an inner loop.

Comment: @EricJ. Sure, if you can get it for free, 40% is great. In this case, however, you get it in exchange for introducing potentially incorrect behavior, which may or may not be acceptable, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Using this method:

```
    private static int Parse(string s)
    {
        int value = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            value = value*10 + (s[i] - '0');
        }
        return value;
    }
```

I get **750 ms** instead of **18+ seconds** with `int.Parse` for 100M conversions.

I won't recommend it unless this is your real bottleneck and you don't care about any form of validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re reading your integers from a `Stream`, then you could optimize by avoiding the overhead of initializing a string.

For example, assuming that your numbers will always be non-negative and terminated by a `,` character, you could use:

```
int num = stream.ReadByte() - '0';
byte next = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
while (next != ',')
{
    num = num * 10 + next - '0';
    next = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToInt32()` uses `Int32.Parse()` (with a little validation thrown in). `Int32.Parse()` in turn uses `Number.Parse()`.

The actual implementation is about as fast as you could get unless you had significant knowledge regarding the input value (e.g. your input is always a fixed number of digits, it is never hex, has a certain precision, it is always unsigned, etc.)

```
private unsafe static Boolean NumberToInt64(ref NumberBuffer number, ref Int64 value) {

    Int32 i = number.scale;
    if (i > Int64Precision || i < number.precision) {
        return false;
    }
    char* p = number.digits;
    BCLDebug.Assert(p != null, "");
    Int64 n = 0;
    while (--i >= 0) {
        if ((UInt64)n > (0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF / 10)) {
            return false;
        }
        n *= 10;
        if (*p != '\0') {
            n += (Int32)(*p++ - '0');
        }
    }
    if (number.sign) {
        n = -n;
        if (n > 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (n < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    value = n;
    return true;
}
```

I use the `Convert.ToXYZ()` methods extensively in my own base framework and in profiler sessions they represent a trivial amount of overhead even when called hundreds of times in a single operation (such as deserializing a complex object tree).

I have encountered places where it is possible to improve upon the performance of the BCL with a specialized algorithm, but this probably isn't one of them.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int) benchmarks 4 techniques. The fastest method was as Romain wrote about above:

```
y = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s[x].Length; i++)
    y = y * 10 + (s[x][i] - '0');
```

Here are some [other methods that were tested](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int) that proved almost 10x slower (where "s" is the array of strings the author used for conversion) :

```
int.Parse(s[x]);
Int32.TryParse(s[x], out y);
Convert.ToInt32(s[x]);
```